# Does Admob Ad Banner on-screen visibility affects the revenue?

Tags: android, admob

I have Ad Banner on the bottom of the `ScrollView`, means which is not visible on the screen without scrolling all the way down. But it is initialized.

Does it affect the revenue? Is there difference in revenue when ad is inside the screen or out side the screen.

Comment: I think it still affect the revenue when you call 'loadAd'. But it's not recommended. You need to put Banner out of the ScrollView. Please read it: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877

Comment: what is the point of adding ad if user's may not see it.It may happen that user may not scroll the full screen.It is better advised to keep the add such that user's can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will affect the revenue, because the user will not readily see it.
The standard approach is to put the AdView outside of the ScrollView.